# How to get the unformated timestamp from mySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Simple question, but still didn't found the answer. I'm storing the records in a table with one field as current timestamp (the field type is timestamp). However, when I do a SELECT, the value returned is a formatted string (like this: 2013-06-26 10:07:06), and I need the number so I can convert to another kind of date. Is there some mySQL setup, or instruction, or a php instruction?

Comment: How would that be easier than just using the real date functions?

Comment: I'm sending to Flash that converts to a date and process it, make comparisons, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a unix timestamp (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Col1)
FROM   yourtable
```

Comment: I'm using SELECT * FROM midia so the php pos-processing instruction is easier to implement. But in SQL probably will be faster, right? Better keep this solution at hand...

Comment: @GustavoPinent you could use this `SELECT midia.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Col1) AS Col1 FROM midia` that returns all columns from midia and one more column with the converted date

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime($timestamp)` in php to convert it to a timestamp if you need to.

Comment: This will works just fine. However, I think the sql command suggested by fthiella is a better practice since the data is sent to php already right, no need to another process. Thanks.